# What exactly causes the "unable to get local issuer certificate" error when accessing an otherwise accessible (via browser) website URL?

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests

I'm on macOS Monterey 12.3 running Python 3.9.7 installed via `brew`. Given this minimal replication of my production code:

```py
import requests

try:
    response = requests.get(website)

except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:
    print("Error: " + str(e))
```

... it spits out this error:

```
Error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<SNIP>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

Unfortunately, the website URL is something that I cannot share. But it's definitely accessible via HTTPS on Chrome. I'm aware of workarounds and have successfully fixed it by following [this one](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/solve-the-dreadful-certificate-issues-in-python-requests-module-2020d922c72f), but I have deployed the same identical code on a Linux server and it errors out all the same (so I'm assuming this isn't a MacOS specific issue). Is this a misconfiguration of the SSL cert on the server? And if so, how is it fixed?

Comment: A lot web servers are not configured correctly and forget to send the intermediate CA certificate(s). To bypass such mistakes web browsers contain a large list of intermediate-certificates additionally to the trusted root certificates. Languages like Python, Java, ... do not contain such lists so they are not able to verify the complete certificate chain and thus fail.